# React.js. (react-countdown-now) How to pass a link on method from from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In class below i use this package to implement countdown timer:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-now#renderer. My class have method "this.props.clearCookies()", and i need to invoke it when timer ends up.  provides property "rerenderer" to get access to variable "completed" and expects function on input. But this.props is unavailable from inputed function. I confused,  how to pass link to this.props.clearCookies() in it?

```
import React from 'react';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';


export default class TransactionPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    renderer({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) {
        if (completed) { 
            // I need to run this.prop.clearCookies() here, but it's not available.
            // I need help to figure out how to invoke it
            this.props.clearCookies().bind(this)
            return 'Транзакция просрочена';
        } 
        else { return <span>Истекает через {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}</span> }
    };

    render(){
        return ( 
        // Here! It's <Countdown /> from react-countdown-now. 
        // It provides a property "rerenderer" to change  representation of timer. Also "rerenderer" is a way to get access to variable "completed". 
        <Countdown date={this.props.dataStamp + 6000} renderer={ this.renderer } burn={this.props.burnCookies} /> 
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure that i have wrote title correct, i don't understand how to explain my issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React-countdown-now has the `onComplete` function https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-now#oncomplete

Use this function to call this.props.clearCookies.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';


export default class TransactionPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    renderer({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) {
        if (completed) { 
            return 'Транзакция просрочена';
        } 
        else { return <span>Истекает через {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}</span> }
    };

    render(){
        return ( 
        <Countdown 
            onComplete={() => this.props.clearCookies()}
            date={this.props.dataStamp + 6000} renderer={ this.renderer } burn={this.props.burnCookies} /> 
        }
    }
}
```

`onComplete` callback is better place for `this.props.clearCookies` than `renderer` function because `render` function is just mapping (`(props, state) => View`), and calling this.props.clearCookies will cause sideeffects

But if you want to call this.props.clearCookies in renderer, you should to bind context of renderer function:

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.renderer = this.renderer.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The renderer method isnt bound to the component instance.  Also `this.props.clearCookies().bind(this)` doesn't make any sense.  The simplest thing to do is add `this.renderer = this.renderer.bind(this)` in your constructor and remove the `.bind(this)` in the implementation.